# Having inner classes and interfaces in Data class of Kotlin is best practice or not

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, inner-classes, android-mvvm

I have a data class which is a room entity and the code is below

```
@Entity(tableName = "request")
data class Request(
@PrimaryKey
var id: Int,
var name: String,
var date: String,
var requestTime: String,
var deliveryTime: String,
var distanceCovered: String
){
interface OnClickListener{
    fun onClick(request: Request)
}

class Adapter(
    private val requests: List<Request>,
    private val requestsFor: Int,
    private val listener: Request.OnClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object{
        const val REQUESTS_FOR_SEND = 0
        const val REQUESTS_FOR_ONGOING = 1
        const val REQUESTS_FOR_COMPLETED = 2
    }

    class ViewHolder(
        var recyclerViewRequestBinding: RequestBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(recyclerViewRequestBinding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        ViewHolder(
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.request,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    override fun getItemCount() = requests.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val request = requests[position]
        holder.recyclerViewRequestBinding.request = request
        when(requestsFor){
            REQUESTS_FOR_COMPLETED ->{
                holder.itemView.request_date.hide()
                holder.itemView.request_delivery_time.show()
                holder.itemView.request_distance_covered.show()
            }
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { listener.onClick(requests[position]) }
    }
}
}
```

Here you can see that `Request` is an `Room` entity and it has its inner class `Adapter` and interface `OnClickListener` having these thing inside the entity is a good practice or not if it is a bad practice then what is the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [SOLID](https://www.baeldung.com/solid-principles) rules, Every class should have single responsibility. You can make `ViewHolder` inner class of Your `Adapter`. Interfaces and Entities should be separated.